# How to change home page only in WordPress

Tags: wp-admin, homepage

I am a newbie in WordPress theme development. I have a WordPress site on online. I create a new home page for my wp site and I want to use it my wp site instead of old home page. And I want that the other pages would stay same as before. In that case, what should I do? Please share the details information.

And if anybody knows good tutorial about changing home page only, please feel free to share it. Thank you.

N.B. In that case, may I create child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom template for this purpose. Create a new file homepage.php and write the below code.

```
  <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Homepage
    */
   ?>
  <?php
  <!--Your code goes here-->
  ?>
```

Then, create a new page in admin panel like HOME and in right sidebar select your "homepage" template you just created. Do not forget answer given by WisdmLabs. You will also have to follow those answer.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to create child theme to assign a page as Home page. 
Goto Wordpress dashboard (wp-admin), there is Appearance menu on left menubar.
 Select Customize under Appearance. 
Here you select the last option 'Static Front Page'. 
Click on radio option 'Front Page', and under 'Front Page' dropdown select a page that you have created for Home page.

Also you can refer to codex link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page